# Going through recursive functions

Tags: c, recursion

I'm looking at the answer key for an exam I took a while back. The question asks for a recursive function that searches a linked list and returns a pointer to a node with data divisible by 3, or NULL if nothing is divisible by 3.

The answer is:

```
struct node { 
 int data; 
 struct node *next; 
}; 

struct node * divThree(struct node * head) { 

 if (head == NULL) 
 return NULL; 

 if (head->data % 3 == 0) 
 return head; 

 return divThree(head->next); 
}
```

How does this function continue tracking through the linked list if neither the head node or next node is divisible by 3? I only see it checking head and the data pointed to by head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a recursive function, when you do the:

```
return(head->next);
```

It checks the `next` node, and repeats the whole function on that `next` node, and when that doesn't comply with the condition, it checks for the `next`, that will be `head->next->next`, and when that doesn't either, it will check the `next` until the end of the list or until finding the result.

Answer (score 1):

`divThree(x)` will call `divThree(x->next)` which in turn will call `divThree(x->next->next)` which will call `divThree(x->next->next->next)` and so on until `divThree` is  called with a parameter `z` such that either `z == NULL` or `z->data % 3 == 0`.